# Including a .text.erb partial in a .html.erb template? (Invoice)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial, erb, invoice

I'm porting an application to Rails 3.

We're an e-commerce site and naturally we send copies of tax invoices by email.  We use plain text, so a `.text.erb` seems logical.

We also display invoices in an area of the user profile, inside `<pre></pre>` tags.  Is there are way I can share a partial between plain text mailer templates, and views in HTML?  If I try to `render "shared/invoice"` inside my HTML ERB template, it says the partial doesn't exist, and that's because it's a `.text.erb` partial.

What are my options, without duplicating code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this in Rails 3, but in Rails 2 you could specify the format of the partial. Might be worth giving it a go on Rails 3.

```
render :partial => "shared/invoice.text.erb"
```

Comment: Any idea if I can escape that content? Obviously the .text.erb doesn't escape characters like `<`, so they are being interpreted as HTML here. Is there an inverse of `html_safe`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could try wrapping it in html_escape

Comment: Hackalicious: `<%= "" + render("shared/invoice.text.erb") %>`. I'll have to move this to a `render_text` helper for clarity.